# How to compile MobileVLC for iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, vlc

I'm trying to compile the Mobile VLC project but it always fails with the buildMobileVLC.sh script. Several different issues occur.

Can someone post instructions on how to build the MobileVLC project so that it runs properly on a device?

Thank you,

apptunes

Comment: [whathaveyoutried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?  are there any instructions for the MobileVLC project to begin with?  What kind of errors are you getting? (edit your question to show screenshots or log output)

Comment: Let me add that there're instructions, but the build script failed on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following thread, and specifically [this answer](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=108691#p368533).
I will not paste the answer here as it's redundant, but if you follow the steps you'll get VLC to compile for iOS. The one thing that I am still having trouble with is being able to visualize multicast rdp/udp streams. HTTP stuff works fine, e.g. 3gp files etc... And of course standard files uploaded via iTunes work without a problem.